# Remove <br /> from email preview after using nl2br

Tags: php, email, html-email

I am trying to send a plain version of a message. I stripped all the html from it and I still want to preserve the line breaks everywhere.

Hotmail apparently doesn't like html and marks emails with html as spam, so to work around that, I am trying to add `nl2br($message)` and that works.

The only problem is, in the email preview (on the iphone) - right before you click to open that email, it shows a bunch of `<br />` which makes it look shady. But once you open the email, it's perfect like it is supposed to be with all the line breaks.

How can I go about keeping the line breaks and not go to the spam with this annoying hotmail email service?

Comment: If you want to have line breaks in plain text messages, just press enter in your text/code editor. Plain text messages shouldn't contain `<br>` or `\n`, although you could try `\n\n` but I doubt that'll work. Use PHPmailer or Swiftmailer if you're not already using it. They have all those goodies ready for you to use.

Comment: im using PHPmailer. If i don't use nl2br, I get no line breaks where I should have them.. I tried pressing enter but all the text shows in one line, so that's not working

Comment: Why not stick with `nl2br($message)` then?

Comment: Show the phpmailer code you're using; The cause for this is in that piece of code.

Comment: @l'L'l it's the regular phpmailer as I downloaded it. I didn't change anything in there. @ Fred, please read my question. I tried it and it worked, but it shows <br /> on the iphone preview area

Comment: any ideas how to fix it?